# Is it possible to create a multichannel `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` from a multichannel `HTMLAudioElement`?

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

It's possible to load a multichannel WAV (i.e. first order ambisonics) file using an html `<audio>` element, and create a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` from that element.

Regarding the `channelCount` property of that `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`, the documentation states that this will depend on the `HTMLMediaElement` the node was created from, but when trying this the channel count is always 2.

Is it possible to create a node that has the channel count corresponding to the number of channels of the loaded file ?

Best,
N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems like all tracks are loaded and played back, you just need to adjust some values. I set the channel count to 4 and channel interpretation to discrete, then used a channel splitter to route the channels individually to an analyzer, e voila, I can see all the different waveforms. Example below.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Multitrack Experiment </h1> 

    <p>This is a little experiment to see if all channels of a multichannel audio file are played back,
    which they are.</p>
    
    <p>The audio file contains four different waveforms on four channels. (0 -> sine, 1 -> saw, 2 -> square, 3 -> noise)</p>
    
    <audio src="tracktest.wav"></audio>
    
    <button>
      <span>Play/Pause</span>
    </button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    <canvas id="oscilloscope"></canvas>

  </body>
  <script>
    // for legacy browsers
    //const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    var playing = false;
    
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // get the audio element
    const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
    
    // pass it into the audio context
    // configure the mediaelement source correctly
    // (otherwise it still shows 2 channels)
    // also change channel interpretation while you're at it ...
    const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    track.outputChannels = 4;
    track.channelInterpretation = 'discrete';

    // just for monitoring purposes
    track.connect(audioContext.destination);

    // split channels to be able to 
    const splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(4);
    track.connect(splitter);
        
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;

    // uncomment the different options to see the different results ...
    splitter.connect(analyser, 0, 0);
    //splitter.connect(analyser, 1, 0);
    //splitter.connect(analyser, 2, 0);
    //splitter.connect(analyser, 3, 0);

    // select our play button
    const playButton = document.querySelector('button');

    playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
    if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
            audioContext.resume();
    }

    console.log(track)
    
    // play or pause track depending on state
    if (!playing) {
        console.log("play");
            audioElement.play();
            playing = true;
    } else {
        console.log("stop");
            audioElement.pause();
        playing = false;
            
    }

    }, false);

    const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);


    // Get a canvas defined with ID "oscilloscope"
    const canvas = document.getElementById("oscilloscope");
    const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw an oscilloscope of the current audio source

    function draw() {

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";

    canvasCtx.beginPath();

    const sliceWidth = canvas.width * 1.0 / bufferLength;
    let x = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

        const v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
        const y = v * canvas.height / 2;

        if (i === 0) {
        canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
        canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        x += sliceWidth;
    }

    canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
    canvasCtx.stroke();
    }

    draw();

  </script>
</html>
```